# Is there a simple way to create a tag pair (<TagName> value</TagName>) in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

Is there a built in function (I know I can easily create one) to create simple tags:

MakeTag("Tag","myvalue")  would generate:
`<Tag>myvalue</Tag>`

I'd rather something simpler than an XML class and all I need is just a tag created like this.

Also, any suggestions on a parser for the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without rolling your own implementation, [`HtmlGenericControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) is about as close as you are going to get:

```
var control = new HtmlGenericControl("Tag") { InnerText = "myvalue" };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `TagBuilder` class in ASP.NET MVC.

I would use LINQ for simple parsing:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing